# Making Images Uploaded Into Screwturn Available To Multiple Pages

Tags: screwturn

Is there a way to make images uploaded into the wiki from one page available to any other pages?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I've decided to just use an html img link instead for expediency's sake, though if you have an answer, please do.  It's always good to have more than one way to get something done.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean with other wiki pages or in another site external of the wiki?

Comment: Hi BuddhaLite, you're new here, but next time you might ask clarifying questions in the comments below the post. Although a ligitimate question, your current answer doesn't answer the original post.

Comment: Fair enough however I can't comment on it.  "add comment (requires 50 reputation)".  This is the only way I could ask for clarification so that I could potentially assist.

Comment: oh, that is true, I forgot. If you're a user on other StackExchange sites, you can connect accounts and get a 'network bonus' (or something like that) of +100. In the mean time, I've voted your answer up :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Path to specify the location of common images.  For example, the following wiki markup:

```
[imageauto|Sample Png Image|/images/SampleImage.png]
```

would display the "SampleImage.png" image file located in the "/images" folder off the web site root folder.  "Sample Png Image" is the caption footer, which you could leave blank.

Check the wiki help page at [WikiMarkup Reference](http://www.screwturn.eu/Help.WikiMarkup.ashx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the server path (something that most admins would not or should not know), you just need to specify the page the image is "attached" to:

```
[imageauto||{UP(<namespace>.<pagename>)}image.jpg]
```

Where `<namespace>` and `<pagename>` are replaced as required.

If you a referencing an attachment in the `<root>` namespace, omit the namespace and dot entirely:

```
[imageauto||{UP(<pagename>)}image.in.root.jpg]
```

Unlike like cross-namespace linking, where a `++` is required, no such addition is required to reference attachments.